# C# How to investigate a OutOfMemoryException in production

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-6, out-of-memory

We have a WCF service developed in C# running in a production environment where it crashes every few hours with no observable pattern. Memory usage will hover at ~250mb for a while, then all of a sudden memory usage starts going up until it crashes with an OutOfMemoryException at 4gb (it's a 32bit process).

We have a hard time identifying the problem, our exceptions logged are from different places in the code, presumably from another request trying to use some memory and it receive the exception.

We have taken a memory dump when the process is at 4gb and a list of ~750k database objects is in memory when the crash occurs. We have looked up the queries of those said objects but can't pinpoint the one that loads up the entire table. The service make calls to the database using EF6.

Another thing to note, this problem never occured in our preproduction environment. The data in the database is sufficient in our preproduction environment for this to occur, if it were to load the entire table also. It's probably a specific call with a specific parameter that triggers this issue, but we can't pinpoint it.

I am out of ideas what to try next to solve our issues. Is there a tool that can help us in this situation ?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a case of memory creeping up over time (which is never fun to track down).  You have this tagged as WCF, so are we looking at the IIS Worker Process (w3wp.exe) throwing the OOM exception?

Comment: The service is a windows service. I have seen the issue happen live and memory goes up rather fast, it takes about a minute to go from ~250mb up to 4gb. This is when I was able to take a memory dump.

Comment: But still, it's a process running indefinitely receiving incoming requests, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, while the memory usage is growing it receives other requests. It processes several requests per minute.

Comment: Have you tried logging all your sql to see what queries are being run?

Comment: I would start looking for instances of your `DbContext` not getting disposed.  That would absolutely cause this

Comment: Have you looked into the DebugDiag tool (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924)? You can configure it to take process dumps when memory reaches a threshold, e.g., when it suddenly starts growing. You should configure to then dump every e.g., minute. You can then compare the dumps to see what is different and hopefully therefore pinpoint the cause.

Comment: To add to what @SteveDanner says, are you implementing IDisposable in places it is needed?

Comment: @Alex We have some logs server side for SQL, I have asked our DBA if he could spot anything, but he did not. For this we would need to run a SQL trace on the database until the problem occurs ?

Comment: The last place I worked at found a bug in production. The sql adapters weren't being disposed of properly and was causing memory bloats. Check your repositories to make sure you are properly closing out your adapters and disposing them.

Comment: Did you look at Event Viewer?
Also consider reviewing your code if there are many `static` variables. Also use `using` statements for your `DbContext`

Comment: Our DBContext is always instancied in a using block. using (DbContext context = new DbContext()) { ... } so it should dispose properly once the request is completed. I will look over every request again to be 100% sure it's the case everywhere, since it could explain the issue indeed.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I will take the time to review our code for the DbContext and try and log our SQL database requests to ensure no requests are returning the entire table. I will report back when our issue is solved. I'm sure it could help anyone with a similar situation.

Comment: You may also use this free tool https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/freetools/sqlcheck to check for long running queries, it will show blue (unclosed db connections) and red balls (long-running transactions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture all your SQL and are using Entity, you can print out queries like this 
`Context.Database.Log = s => Debug.Print(s);`

If you mess around with that a bit you can get it to output to a variable and save the result to text file or Db. You would have to wrap it around all Db calls-not sure how big your project is?

`Context.Database.Log = null;`

turns it off

Comment: That's interesting, I figured it could be done using Entity Framework. This should help us since running a SQL Trace for hours might not be the best solution on a production server. 

The project is rather big, but our memory dump indicated us which entities are loaded so we'll start logging requests to those entities first.